# working with cakephp pagination with advance filter

Tags: pagination, cakephp-2.0

I am working on Ecommerce website where i need some advance filter like price, types.

**Controller**

```
public function index($category) {
$this->set('category',$category);
$this->loadModel("Product");    

$conditions['Product.category'] = $category;    
if(!empty($this->request->data['filter']['materialtype']))
{
foreach($this->request->data['filter']['materialtype'] as $v)
{       
$this->set('v',$v); 
$conditions['OR'][]['Product.materialtype LIKE'] ="%$v%";
}
}
$this->set('agetProduct',$this->paginate($conditions));
```

}

**View**
[image]

**INITIAL QUERY WORKING FINE**

```
1 SELECT `Product`.`id`, `Product`.`category`, `Product`.`materialtype`, `Product`.`occasion`, `Product`.`collections`, `Product`.`stone`, `Product`.`sku`, `Product`.`name`, `Product`.`goldkaratage`, `Product`.`weight`, `Product`.`stoneweight`, `Product`.`diamondcaratage`, `Product`.`diamondcolor`, `Product`.`diamondclarity`, `Product`.`picture1`, `Product`.`picture2`, `Product`.`picture3`, `Product`.`picture4`, `Product`.`picture5`, `Product`.`picture6`, `Product`.`price`, `Product`.`description`, `Product`.`featured`, `Product`.`action` FROM `mookim`.`products` AS `Product` WHERE `Product`.`category` = 'Pendant' LIMIT 12
2   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `mookim`.`products` AS `Product` WHERE `Product`.`category` = 'Pendant'
```

**WHEN I CLICK ON ADVANCE FILTER CHECKBOX FOLLOWING QUERY IS GENERATE WHICH IS ALSO FINE THIS MYSQL QUERY CONTAINS 14 RECORD WHERE 12 PRODUCTS SET ON FIRST PAGE AND REST ARE ON SECOND PAGE**

```
 1 SELECT `Product`.`id`, `Product`.`category`, `Product`.`materialtype`, `Product`.`occasion`, `Product`.`collections`, `Product`.`stone`, `Product`.`sku`, `Product`.`name`, `Product`.`goldkaratage`, `Product`.`weight`, `Product`.`stoneweight`, `Product`.`diamondcaratage`, `Product`.`diamondcolor`, `Product`.`diamondclarity`, `Product`.`picture1`, `Product`.`picture2`, `Product`.`picture3`, `Product`.`picture4`, `Product`.`picture5`, `Product`.`picture6`, `Product`.`price`, `Product`.`description`, `Product`.`featured`, `Product`.`action` FROM `mookim`.`products` AS `Product` WHERE `Product`.`category` = 'Pendant' AND ((`Product`.`materialtype` LIKE '%Yellow Gold%') OR (`Product`.`materialtype` LIKE '%White Gold%') OR (`Product`.`materialtype` LIKE '%Silver%')) LIMIT 12

2   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `mookim`.`products` AS `Product` WHERE `Product`.`category` = 'Pendant' AND ((`Product`.`materialtype` LIKE '%Yellow Gold%') OR (`Product`.`materialtype` LIKE '%White Gold%') OR (`Product`.`materialtype` LIKE '%Silver%'))
```

**BUT TO SEE NEXT PRODUCT OF FILTER QUERY WHEN I CLICK ON NEXT PAGE MY QUERY IS COMPLETELY CHANGED NOW I SEE FOLLOWING QUERY WHICH CONTAINS ALL RECORD OF SQL TABLE**

```
1 SELECT `Product`.`id`, `Product`.`category`, `Product`.`materialtype`, `Product`.`occasion`, `Product`.`collections`, `Product`.`stone`, `Product`.`sku`, `Product`.`name`, `Product`.`goldkaratage`, `Product`.`weight`, `Product`.`stoneweight`, `Product`.`diamondcaratage`, `Product`.`diamondcolor`, `Product`.`diamondclarity`, `Product`.`picture1`, `Product`.`picture2`, `Product`.`picture3`, `Product`.`picture4`, `Product`.`picture5`, `Product`.`picture6`, `Product`.`price`, `Product`.`description`, `Product`.`featured`, `Product`.`action` FROM `mookim`.`products` AS `Product` WHERE `Product`.`category` = 'Pendant' LIMIT 12, 12      5   5   1
2   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `mookim`.`products` AS `Product` WHERE `Product`.`category` = 'Pendant'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index($category) {
$this->set('category',$category);
$this->loadModel("Product");    
$conditions['Product.category'] = $category;
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
if(!empty($this->params['url']['data']['filter']['materialtype']))
{   
foreach ($this->params['url']['data']['filter']['materialtype'] as $v){
$conditions['OR'][]['Product.materialtype LIKE'] ="%$v%";
}
}


$this->paginate = array('limit' => 12,'conditions' => $conditions);
$agetProduct = $this->paginate($this->modelClass);
$this->set(compact('agetProduct'));   
}
```

**VIEW USE FORM METHOD GET**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('filter', array('url'=>array('controller'=>'Products', 'action'=>'index',$category),'id'=>'filter','autocomplete'=>'off','type'=>'get'));?>
```